# Array count values

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I am new to php, i have some problem in php page. This page contain one while loop, in that loop itself taking record from data base, it showing taxt box, list box like this,,,etc..Here php page while loop contain more then 5 records. here i need to select list box value to pass post to set session in next page. From that session i have take value to show next php page.
So here which type array i have to use,...and using get am going to pass value ,,,but value is 0 coming without selecting value,,..if am select list box value it ll come null value,,please suggest how can i pass whole value to next page,...

thanks
periyasamy

Comment: I guess it's best you get yourself a good book on PHP and start to learn it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Insert the contents of the data from the previous page into the form that posts to the next page, in the form of `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />`. Then, pull it out of the `$_POST` array on the next page.

About the `<select>` element returning NULLs, try specifying the `name` attribute on the `<select>` element, and a `value` attribute on each of the `<option>` elements. Don't forget to have one with the `selected="selected"` attribute set, to specify a default.